# Linear algebra MCQ.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ and $y=(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be linearly independent . Let $\delta_{1}=x_{2}y_{3}-y_{2}x_{3},\delta_{2}=x_{1}y_{3}-y_{1}x_{3},\delta_{3}=x_{1}y_{2}-y_{1}x_{2}$. If $V$ is span of $x,y$ then

$1. V=\{(u,v,w):\delta_{1}u-\delta_{2}v+\delta_{3}w=0\}$

$2. V=\{(u,v,w):-\delta_{1}u+\delta_{2}v+\delta_{3}w=0\}$

$3. V=\{(u,v,w):\delta_{1}u+\delta_{2}v-\delta_{3}w=0\}$

$4. V=\{(u,v,w):\delta_{1}u+\delta_{2}v+\delta_{3}w=0\}$

I tried it as follows

Since the dimension of the vector space $V$ is 2 so any three vectors will be linearly dependent . If we choose three vectors $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}),(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})$ and $(u,v,w)$ then these three vectors are linearly dependent which  gives $\delta_{1}u-\delta_{2}v+\delta_{3}w=0$ . This gives me $1$st option as answer but i don't know the exact ideal. Please suggest me proper solution of this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\delta=(\delta_1,-\delta_2,\delta_3)$ satisfies the following relation :

$$\delta=x \times y$$

with $\times$ the cross product. Because of the properties of the cross product, $\delta$ is orthogonal to both $x$ and $y$ -try to do the scalar product-. Thus $\delta$ is a normal vector of $V$.

If a plane has $(a,b,c)$ as a normal vector, then it verifies the equation $au+bv+cw=0$.

So the answer here is 1.

Comment: But answer is first one....

Comment: According to you $\delta=(0,1,1)$

Comment: I think we should take $\delta=(\delta_{1},-\delta_{2},\delta_{3})$??

Comment: Sorry you're right, this is not exaclty the cross product, I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***:- Let $(u,v,w)$ be in the span of $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$. Now, Consider the  matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} x_1&y_1&u\\x_2&y_2&v\\x_3&y_1&w \end{bmatrix}$. Now it can be easily observed that $\rho(A)=2$, giving $|A|=0$. The last equation is equivalent to $(1)$.

Comment: ok thanks.............

Comment: welcome ..........